# react state can not read property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing an issue with react , it worked with individual usestates but when I made it as an object it failed , and this is the code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import {DatabaseNetworkPoint} from '@icon-park/react';
import axios from "axios"

export default function Register() {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        username:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
        age:0,
        gender:"",
    })
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null)

  


    const handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        setUser({
            username:event.target.value,
        email:event.target.value,
        password:event.target.value,
        age:event.target.value,
        gender:event.target.value,
        img:event.target.files[0]
        })

        setFile(event.target.files[0])
    
    }
      

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('button clicked', event.target)
      }

  
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='left'>
       <div className='logo'>
       <DatabaseNetworkPoint theme="outline" size="150" fill="#333"/>
        <h1>WonderHit</h1>
       </div>
          <form className='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input placeholder='Username' value={user.username} className='field' type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
          <input placeholder='Email' value={user.email} className='field' type="email" onChange={handleChange} />
          <input placeholder='Password' value={user.password} className='field' type="password" onChange={handleChange} />
          <input placeholder='Age' value={user.age} className='field' name='age' type="number" onChange={handleChange} />
          <input placeholder='Gender' value={user.gender} className='field' name='gender' type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
          <div className='profilePic'>
            <div className='Photo'></div>
            <input className='field2' id='file' type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor = "file"  className='uploadPic' >+</label>
          </div>
          <button className='submit' type="submit">Register</button>
          <h3 className='routing'>You already have an account ? <Link className='rot' to="/">Login</Link></h3>
        </form>
      </div>
      <img className='right' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562577309-4932fdd64cd1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80' />
    </div>
  )
}
```

and this is the error Iam getting :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
what might be the problem ?? is it the file thats causing me issues ? should I handle it as string ??????

Comment: Add a if statement to check e.target

Answer (score 0):

`img:event.target.files[0]`
You're calling handleChange for every `<input>`, whether it's a file type or not.

Comment: what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different handler, don't use the same handler(**handleChange**) for every input change, the issue is coming because of another field change file type input returning null.

Use another handler for the upload file and set it to use of useState and use it for a later use case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a check to your `handleChange(event)`'s event, and make a conditional setting to your `user` state. Also remember using new object when setting `user` state, because you would like to save the other input's state in your `user`

```js
  const handleChange = (event) => {
        if(event.target.placeholder === 'Username'){
          //  use {...user, [update]: event.target.value }
          setUser({...user, username:event.target.value });
        }  
        //else if (){ ...other input}
        
        if(event.target.id = 'file'){
          setFile(event.target.files[0])
        }  
    }
```

a simple example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
      function App () {
        const [user, setUser] = React.useState({});
        
        const handleChange = (e) => {
          if (e.target.placeholder === "Username") {
            setUser({...user, username: e.target.value});
          }
          if (e.target.placeholder === "Email") {
            setUser({...user, email: e.target.value});
          }
          if (e.target.placeholder === "Password") {
            setUser({...user, password: e.target.value});
          }
          if (e.target.placeholder === "Age") {
            setUser({...user, age: e.target.value});
          }
          if (e.target.placeholder === "Gender") {
            setUser({...user, gender: e.target.value});
          }
          
          console.log(e.target);
          
          if(e.target.id === "file"){
            if (e.target.files) {
              const img = document.getElementById("img");
              console.log(img);
              img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
            } 
          }
        }
        
        return <div>
          <div>Inputs</div>
          <input placeholder='Username' value={user.username} className='field' type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
          <input placeholder='Email' value={user.email} className='field' type="email" onChange={handleChange} />
          <input placeholder='Password' value={user.password} className='field' type="password" onChange={handleChange} />
          <input placeholder='Age' value={user.age} className='field' name='age' type="number" onChange={handleChange} />
          <input placeholder='Gender' value={user.gender} className='field' name='gender' type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
          <div>file (only accept photo)</div>
          <input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleChange}></input>
          <div>User Object's props</div>
          <div>user.username: {user.username}</div>
          <div>user.email: {user.email}</div>
          <div>user.password: {user.password}</div>
          <div>user.age: {user.age}</div>
          <div>user.gender: {user.gender}</div>
          <br />
          <div>image display</div>
          <img id="img"></img>
        </div>
      }
    </script>

    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(
            <App></App>
            , document.getElementById("root"));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because this line `setFile(event.target.files[0])` you should first check existing of `event.target.files` then set it in your state;

`event.target.files && setFile(event.target.files[0])`